# How to allow all IPs which start with 192.168 in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin you can allow %, which stands for all IPs.
But is there a way to allow all IPs from my local network 
(something like 192.168.%) ?

So basically that I can always access the DB inside the network but I can forward the port as well without letting „hackers“ inside the DB without a password.

I know that I normally could give my pc a static IP but my router isn't doing that (he's a real jackass) and it would be nice to access other computers DBs in the network.

If you know how to do that, I would be thankful if you help me out.

Kind regards
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html) you can do it via providing allowed IP with wildcards for allowed parts.

In your case it should be `'192.168.%.%'`.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks